# CakePHP & Twitter Bootstrap: tooltip on table header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, html-table, tooltip

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to implement a tooltip over a table header `<th>` with Twitter Bootstrap 2 and CakePHP 2.
Tooltips are working for buttons (so JQuery etc. is working).
Example for a button with a working tooltip:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->postLink('Send', array(
    'action' => 'send'), array(
        'class' => 'btn', 
        'title' => 'Send it back', 
        'rel' => 'tooltip', 
        'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 
        'data-placement' => 'bottom'
));
?>
```

Comment: What did yo try? Your question doesn't show a lot of effort what you tried so far, StackOverflow is not meant to have other write your code *for you*

Comment: I tried buttons, links, span, tag. Sorry but there is no example which could help others but the one posted here (for a simple "problem" like a tooltip).

Comment: Based on the documentation: `<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip" class='.ttip'>hover over me</a>`, you should be able to initialise this with `$('.ttip').tooltip();` in your `$(document).ready()`